# Nosuch element exception in selenium but the element is present there

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe, webdriverwait

I was trying to scrape some data from a site.I'm using a selenium for it but i am getting NoSuchElementException when i try to click or get data from the elements in the site even though the element present in there.

code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://www.priceking.com/')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/center/font/a").click()
    # driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div > center > font > a").click()
```

Here is site link that i was using [priceking](https://www.priceking.com/)

i don't know why i can't locate any of the elements in the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Show More</kbd> is in an `iframe`. Need to switch to frame to interact with the element.

```
# Imports required
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.priceking.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Switch to Iframe
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"contents")))

show_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'Show More')]")))
show_more.click()

# Can also use Link text to click on the element.
# show_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Show More")))
# show_more.click()

# switch to default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired element is within a `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.priceking.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='contents']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Show More"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.priceking.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='contents']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Show More')]"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ShowMore]

Answer (score 1):

Please use some `wait` statements before clicking the link and also the  element is inside an `iframe` so switch to frame first then click on the element.

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"contents")))
 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()=' Show More ']")))
 driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()=' Show More ']").click()
```

and always write reliable `xPath`

Answer (score 1):

1. That element is inside a frame, you need to switch to that frame in order to access that element.
2. You have to add some wait / delay before accessing the element.
3. The locator should be improved.
   Try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.priceking.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='contents']")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Show More')]"))).click()
```